# Passing data from Javascript to HTML in real-time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm tired and lost. It seems that a huge part of the challenge of coding in a disjointed MVC / multi-language fashion is figuring out ways to pass values between different parts at the appropriate times.

The following code does not work.

I've got a JS file:

```
// GET DATA FROM A MAP PIN THAT A USER CLICKS ON
// The data is read from our API for that pin.

function getPinData(id, template) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/pins/"+id,
    type: "GET",
    data: "JSON"
  }).success(function(data){

    var pinTitle = data["pin"]["activity"];
    var pinDescription = data["pin"]["description"];
    var pinGuideFirstName = data["pin"]["guide_first_name"];
    var pinGuideLastName = data["pin"]["guide_last_name"];
    var pinGuideRating = data["pin"]["guide_rating"];
    var pinGuideEmail = data["pin"]["guide_email"];

    var guideData = [pinGuideFirstName, pinGuideLastName,
                     pinTitle, pinGuideEmail];

    // the contents of guideData now need to be passed to a different page.

    // jQuery selector - messageGuideButton is simply a button that will bring up a
    // pop-up form that allows the user to send a message to the guide. I want to send          
    // guideData to this html form

    $( "#messageGuideButton" ).on("click", function() {
      $.ajax({
        url: "/message.html",
        type: "GET",
        data: guideData,
        success: function(response) {

          // Checking to see if guideData still exists in this function - it exists

          console.log("Guide Data in AJAX: " + guideData);   

          $('.popin').html(response).fadeIn();
          },
        beforeSend: function() {
          $('.popin').addClass('loading');
          },
        complete: function() {
          $('.popin').removeClass('loading');
          }
        });
      });
    })
}
```

message.html, which is a pop-up box, not a separate page.

```
<div class="ui raised segment signin">
  <div class="cmborder">

    <script>
      console.log("Guide Data in Form: " + guideData); 
      // guideData comes back as undefined
      // I guess arrays can't be passed via GET
    </script>

    // This is Rails code and Rails' form helper methods

    <%= form_tag("/message", method: "post") do %>
      <!-- <p>Go ahead and message your guide</p> -->
      <div class="two fields">
        <div class="inline field">

    // I want to add the guideData into a hidden form field for submission later

         <%= hidden_field_tag 'message[guideFirstName]', guideData[0] %>
        </div>
        <div class="inline field">
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'message[guideLastName]', guideData[1] %>
        </div>
        <div class="inline field">
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'message[pinTitle]', guideData[2] %>
        </div>
        <div class="inline field">
          <%= hidden_field_tag 'message[guideEmail]', guideData[3] %>
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <label>First Name</label>
          <%= text_field_tag 'message[firstName]', @current_user.first_name, class: "ui input", placeholder: "First Name" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Last Name</label>
          <%= text_field_tag 'message[lastName]', @current_user.last_name, class: "ui input", placeholder: "Last Name" %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Message title</label>
        <%= text_field_tag 'message[messageTitle]', nil, class: "ui input", placeholder: "Message Title" %>
      </div>
      <div class="field">
        <label>Message</label>
        <%= text_area_tag 'message[messageBody]', nil, class: "ui input", placeholder: "Message Body" %>
      </div>
      <div class="inline field">
        <%= hidden_field_tag 'message[currentUserEmail]', @current_user.email %>
      </div>
      <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "ui blue submit button" %>

    <% end %>
  <span class='close_message' id="messageclose">&times;</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to transfer the guideData info into the new form. I don't want to just put it in the URL because the guideData could get pretty long.

I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: What error is it throwing? You should click "inspect element" in your page to see which JS errors are showing up.

Comment: Would it be easier to just use something like AngularJS or HandlebarsJS?

Comment: Basically when I click on the #messageGuideButton button, message.html tries to load but never loads. It just gets stuck because it is trying to load guideData and is undefined. If you remove

` console.log("Guide Data in Form: " + guideData); `

it loads right up, but with no data from the JS file, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

when the ajax is called, it goes to the rails server and tries to process the request.  Since `guideData` is a js variable and is not a global one, it is not seen by `message.html`.

Furthermore, you probably have an error when the browser tries to run the ajax.  the data option is invalid.  It's like you're passing `data: [1,2,3]` to `$.ajax` and it's invalid.  Change it to `data: { data: guideData }`, and in `messages.html`, try to change `guideData` to `<%= params[:data] %>`.

Another big issue with `message.html` are the lines similar to

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'message[guideEmail]', guideData[3] %>
```

rails has no access to js variables. If you follow my suggestion above, change `guideData[3]` here to `params[:data][3]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.

What I ended up doing was just using Handlebars.

I made all the pertinent data available in one API URL so I only had to make a single API call in my JS.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/pins/"+id,
    type: "GET",
    data: "JSON"
  }).success(function(data){

    var pinTitle = data["pin"]["activity"];
    var pinDescription = data["pin"]["description"];
    var pinLong = data["pin"]["long"];
    var pinLat = data["pin"]["lat"];
    var pinGuideFirstName = data["pin"]["guide_first_name"];
    var pinGuideLastName = data["pin"]["guide_last_name"];
    var pinGuideRating = data["pin"]["guide_rating"];
    var pinGuideEmail = data["pin"]["guide_email"];
    var pinGuideExperience = data["pin"]["guide_experience"];
    var pinGuideAvatar = data["pin"]["guide_avatar"]["avatar"]["url"];
```

I then bundled the data into a hash object / variable (pinData) and sent pinData into my Handlebars template.

```
var pinData = {
        guideFirstName : pinGuideFirstName,
        guideLastName : pinGuideLastName,
        guideEmail : pinGuideEmail,
        guideExperience : pinGuideExperience,
        guideAvatar : pinGuideAvatar,
        guideRating : pinGuideRating,
        pinActivity : pinTitle,
        pinDescription2 : pinDescription,
        userEmail : currentUserEmail,
        userFirstName : currentUserFirstName,
        userLastName : currentUserLastName
      };

var messageHTML = HandlebarsTemplates['messages/index'](pinData);
```

messageHTML contains the raw HTML code with the Handlebars variables injected right into it.

I then using jQuery to open up a popup window when I click on a button and pass the messageHTML right into it.

```
$( "#messagePinGuideButton" ).on("click", function() {
        $('.popin').html(messageHTML).fadeIn();
      });
```

Pretty easy, very fast, very direct. I like it.